# Uncaught TypeError: useValue,useFactory,data is not iterable! Angular 4 cli project error

Tags: node.js, angular, phantomjs, karma-runner, casperjs

I am new to Angular 4 , I have just created a project by Angular Cli and I get error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: useValue,useFactory,data is not iterable!
```

[image]

I an unable to resolve it. I installed and reinstalled cli , I just want to know how can I resolve it. 
All I did was

```
ng new myprj 
 mkdir myprj 
 ng serve
```

Comment: I am also running into this.  It doesn't show up for me in the browser console, but it does occur in a CasperJS test (under both PantomJS and SlimerJS).

Comment: which browser and what version of that browser are you using?

Comment: This appears to be related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7125

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by adding the es6-shim to a script tag in my index.html file:

< script > src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.22.1/‌​es6-shim.min.js">< /s‌​cript >

I was running into the same issue when running `ng test` during my Travis deployment, even though it executed without error locally.

```
Chromium 37.0.2062 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught TypeError: useValue,useFactory,data is not iterable!
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:830
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding the es6-shim to my index.html file 

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.22.1/es6-shim.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Such error usually happens if a browser is missing new features. Can be easily fixed by including polyfills

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

To your vendor file or to file which start your tests in case you're switched in karma.config.js

```
   browsers: ['Chrome'] to browsers: ['PhantomJS']
```

Or getting this error after running **ng test**

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the same as mine, you need to go to the polyfills.ts file in your project to enable backward compatibility.

There are multiple lines to uncomment and packages to install mentioned in the comments. Some of them are required for the applcation to run on any version of IE.

Helped me.

Comment: But I don't think the OP's issue is related to IE. Which specific line are you suggesting should be uncommented to solve the "useValue,useFactory,data is not iterable!" error?